# Ember: are model initial values null or empty string?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am confused about the **initialisation** values of a new model.

When creating a new record, it seems that all properties have "**null**" as value.

As soon as you type something in the textfield (bound to the model), and then delete the typed value (thus again an empty textfield), the value of the properties becomes **emptystring**.

Is this the expected behaviour ?

There is a difference for REST API's whether they receive null or "" ...

Comment: This really becomes confusing when tabbing through a form field and watching isDirty. If the initial value was null, because it was stored that way in the DB, then you focus on a TextField with 'tab' the value will change to "" and set the record's isDirty param to true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your atribute is `DS.attr('string')`, so this is correct.
Doesn't matter if the string is null or empty, this just represent that the text isn't present. Thinking in programming language you would be aware of the null, because you receive error when accessing methods. But in business rules, doesn't matter if the string is null or empty, so this is a common pattern, for example:

```
if (name == null || name.length == 0) {
  // name is missing, prompt the user ...
}
```

And this is a rare situation:

```
if (name == null) {
  // some logic here
} else if(name == "") {
  // other logic here
}
```

About the record creating. When you create it, the values is null. But when binding to a text field, for example:

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding="field"}}
```

You have this relationship:

```
model.field <-> textfield.value
```

When you set something in `model.field`, it will be syncronized with the textfield and vice-versa. But in the case of editing the textfield, the value will always be a string, this is the reason that you receive a empty string, instead of null, when clearing the textfield.

Comment: Will just need to take care if this situation in the REST API.  The user creates for example a new entity, skips a few fields that he does not complete and the JSON will then include null values; and thus the REST API needs to take care of both null and "" values in JSON.

Comment: Yes, this is correct when the target of that value is a number by example, where null and "" isn't a valid value.

Comment: I looked into a variety of ways to modify inputs to deal with this, and the solution really seems to be to normalize your JSON to only use "" instead of null; even if you store it as NULL in the DB. Setting ```DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: "" })``` didn't help me either.